# Python: how to reshape a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python

I have a dataset containing the indicators of different cities: so the same `indicator` is repeated several times for different cities. The dataset is something like this:

```
df
    city    indicator                   Value
0   Tokio   Solid Waste Recycled        1.162000e+01
1   Boston  Solid Waste Recycled        3.912000e+01
2   London  Solid Waste Recycled        0.000000e+00
3   Tokio   Own-Source Revenues         1.420000e+00
4   Boston  Own-Source Revenues         0.000000e+00
5   London  Own-Source Revenues         3.247000e+01
6   Tokio   Green Area                  4.303100e+02
7   Boston  Green Area                  7.166350e+01
8   London  Green Area                  1.997610e+01
9   Tokio   City Land Area              9.910000e+01
10  Boston  City Land Area              4.200000e+01
11  London  City Land Area              8.956000e+01
```

From the original dataframe I would like to create a second dataframe like the following:

```
 df1
            Solid Waste Recycled  Own-Source Revenues  Green Area    City Land Area
  Tokio     1.162000e+01          1.420000e+00         4.303100e+02  9.910000e+01
  Boston    3.912000e+01          0.000000e+00         7.166350e+01  4.200000e+01
  London    0.000000e+00          3.247000e+01         1.997610e+01
```

Comment: Look into groupby. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there is a better solution, but you can `groupby` and then `apply` a function on each grouped dataframe to create a new one:

```
grouped = df.groupby('City')
res = defaultdict(list)
for k, k_df in grouped:
    res['City'].append(k)
    k_df.apply(lambda row: res[row['Indicator']].append(row['Value']), axis=1)
pd.DataFrame(res)
```

Notice this will work only if all the values appear for all cities. If you want to support missing values you add `None`s for missing values of each city. This requires to collect all possible values and check they were inserted:

```
grouped = df.groupby('City')
res = defaultdict(list)
new_columns = set(df['Indicator']) #all possible values
for k, k_df in grouped:
    res['City'].append(k)
    k_df.apply(lambda row: res[row['Indicator']].append(row['Value']), axis=1)
    for col in new_columns:
        if len(res[col]) < len(res['City']): # check if values is missing
            res[col].append(None)
```